# Error al querer vincular Seasons con Serie en Django REST Framework

Tags: django, djangorestframework

Estoy intentando hacer una API que es de series.

La app es muy muy simple la verdad. Cuenta con Series, Seasons y Episodes.

Dejo los models de cada uno para que puedan ver:

series model:

```
class Serie(SeriesAPIModel):
    """Serie model."""

    title = models.CharField('Series title', max_length=250)
    release = models.DateField('Release date', default=timezone.now())
    description = models.TextField('Series description', blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField('Series image', upload_to='series/images/')

    def __str__(self):
        """Return series title."""
        return self.title
```

seasons model:

```
class Season(SeriesAPIModel):
    """Season model."""

    title = models.CharField('Season title', max_length=250)

    serie = models.ForeignKey(Serie, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        """Return season title and serie."""
        return f'{self.serie}: {self.title}'
```

episodes model:

```
class Episode(SeriesAPIModel):
    """Episode model."""

    title = models.CharField('Episode title', max_length=250)

    video = models.URLField()
    image = models.ImageField('Episode image', upload_to='episodes/images/')

    season = models.ForeignKey(Season, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        """Return episode title, season title and serie."""
        return f'{self.season.serie}: {self.season}: {self.title}'
```

Quiero que al hacer un GET de la serie salgan las temporadas, y tambien que al listar las temporadas salgan los episodios.

Lo que hice ahora fue esto, aunque no funciono:

serializer.py

```
class SerieModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """Serie model serializer."""

    seasons = serializers.StringRelatedField(many=True)

    class Meta:
        """Meta class."""

        model = Serie
        fields = '__all__'


class SeasonModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """Season model serializer."""

    episodes = serializers.StringRelatedField(many=True)

    class Meta:
        """Meta class."""

        model = Season
        fields = '__all__'


class EpisodeModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """Episode model serializer."""

    class Meta:
        """Meta class."""

        model = Episode
        fields = '__all__'
```

Espero que me puedan ayudar, muchas gracias!

Comment: Quieres hacer el api que regrese las temporadas y episodios de cada temporada al mismo tiempo y que esos datos los tome de la base de sqlite de django???

Comment: @Arelis_xzx claro, que al pedir el detalle de una serie me salgan todas las temporadas y episodios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías modificar tus modelos agregando `related_name` a la `ForeignKey` para permitir una relacion inversa (nota que por simplicidad removí algunas propiedades a los modelos)

```
class Serie(models.Model):
    """Serie model."""

    title = models.CharField('Series title', max_length=250)
    release = models.DateField('Release date', default=datetime.now)
    description = models.TextField('Series description', blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        """Return series title."""
        return self.title

class Season(models.Model):
    """Season model."""

    title = models.CharField('Season title', max_length=250)
    serie = models.ForeignKey(Serie, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="seasons")

    def __str__(self):
        """Return season title and serie."""
        return f'{self.serie}: {self.title}'

class Episode(models.Model):
    """Episode model."""

    title = models.CharField('Episode title', max_length=250)
    video = models.URLField()
    season = models.ForeignKey(Season, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="episodes")

    def __str__(self):
        """Return episode title, season title and serie."""
        return f'{self.season.serie}: {self.season}: {self.title}'
```

Posteriormente en los serializers hay que utilizar los serializers de cada modelo (nota que para esto, el orden en el que están escritos es importante) y en los fields hay que utilizar los `related_name` que se agregaron.

```
class EpisodeModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """Episode model serializer."""

    class Meta:
        """Meta class."""
        model = Episode
        fields = ('title',)

class SeasonModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """Season model serializer."""

    episodes = EpisodeModelSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        """Meta class."""
        model = Season
        fields = ('title', 'episodes')

class SerieModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """Serie model serializer."""
    seasons = SeasonModelSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        """Meta class."""
        model = Serie
        fields = ('title', 'description', 'seasons')
```

Finalmente, mis views (Solamente creé un template rápido de prueba. Seguramente tu lo tienes implementado diferente)

```
@api_view(["GET", "POST"])
def ListView(request, api_name):
    object_list = Serie.objects.all()
    serializers  = SerieModelSerializer(object_list, many=True)
    return Response(serializers.data)
```